# Rendering fetched data from supabase in Nextjs13 App Directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I successfully fetched data from supabase but I am unable to render them in my component , I tried implemented a component to hold the fetched data but i was unable to as it arose to other errors then I decided to just render the fetched data in the same component which fetches data but also I was unable to render them . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the source code I am using:

```
"use client"

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Search from "../search"
import { supabase } from "@/app/libs/supabase"
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import toast from "react-hot-toast"
import Profile from "@/components/profile/Profile"
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'

// interface Array{
//    name:string;
// }

interface UserData{
  name:string;
  phone:string;
  email:string;
  prevState:null
}



export default function profile(){
 
  const [profiles,setProfile] = useState<any | null>(null)

    const router = useRouter()

    const res = NextResponse.next()

    useEffect(()=>{
     User()
    },[])

    const User =useCallback(async()=>{
      const {data:{user}} =  await supabase.auth.getUser()



      if(user){
        const{data} = await supabase.from("profiles").select().eq('email',user.email)
        if(data){
           setProfile(data)
          console.log(data)
        }
       
      }
      else{
        const load = toast.loading("Redirecting to Login Page")
           setTimeout(()=>{
            toast.dismiss(load)
           },500)
            router.push('/')
      }
    },[])

    return(
        <>
        <aside className='md:py-5'>
    <Search/>
    </aside>
        
        <section >
            <h4 className='text-bra text-2xl text-center md:text-3xl lg:text-3xl'>My Profile</h4>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
             {profiles && profiles.map((profile: any)=>(<Profile key={profile._id} profile={profile}  />))}
           
            </div>
        </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

below is my Profile.tsx component

```
import React from 'react'
interface ProfileProps{
   name?:string;
   email?:string;
   phone?: string;
}

const profile: ProfileProps={}

const Profile:React.FC<ProfileProps> = () => {
 return (
   <div className='justify-center items-center flex flex-col bg-green-100'>
       <p>Name:{profile.name}</p>
       <p>Email:{profile.email}</p>
       <p>Phone:{profile.phone}</p>
   </div>
 )
}

export default Profile
```

Fetched data and render them in my component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully fixed it by doing the following changes:

```
"use client"

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Search from "../search"
import { supabase } from "@/app/libs/supabase"
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import toast from "react-hot-toast"
import Profile from "@/components/profile/Profile"
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'

// interface Array{
//    name:string;
// }

interface UserData{
  name:string;
  phone:string;
  email:string;
  prevState:null
}



export default function profile(){
  // const [profiles,setProfile] = useState<Record<string, any>[] | null>(null)
  // const [profiles,setProfile] = useState<UserData | null>(null)
  const [profiles,setProfile] = useState<any | null>(null)

    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(()=>{
     User()
    },[])

    const User =useCallback(async()=>{
      const {data:{user}} =  await supabase.auth.getUser()

      if(user){
        const{data} = await supabase.from("profiles").select().eq('email',user.email)
        if(data){
           setProfile(data)
          console.log(data)
        }
       
      }
      else{
        const load = toast.loading("Redirecting to Login Page")
           setTimeout(()=>{
            toast.dismiss(load)
           },500)
            router.push('/')
      }
    },[])

    return(
        <>
        <aside className='md:py-5'>
    <Search/>
    </aside>
        
        <section  >
          <section className="flex items-center py-4 lg:py-0 justify-center">
          <div className=" rounded-full bg-bra px-3 w-48">
            <h4 className='text-white text-2xl text-center md:text-3xl lg:text-3xl'>My Profile</h4>
            </div>
            </section>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center lg:py-4">
            {profiles && profiles.map((profile: any)=>(<Profile key={profile.id} profile={profile}  />))}
  
            </div>
        </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

And my Profile.tsx component

```
import React from 'react'
interface ProfileProps{
    name?:string;
    email?:string;
    phone?: string;
}


const Profile = ({profile}: {profile: ProfileProps}) => {
  return (
    <div className='justify-center items-center rounded-md shadow-md px-4 flex flex-col bg-teal-100'>
        <p>Name:{profile.name}</p>
        <p>Email:{profile.email}</p>
        <p>Phone:{profile.phone}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile
```